# Track android phone with IMEI number of mobile

Tags: android, gps, tracking, imei

In my app I want to get the location of a mobile using it's **IMEI** number.I need guidance please...

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475849/how-to-track-user-location-using-imei-number

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya The answer is teaching the way to get IMEI.I don't want that I have already IMEI I need to track that IMEI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means to get the location of a mobile using its IMEI number, except perhaps via law enforcement agencies and similar groups.